# Firefox is ignoring my margin-bottom css property. Works fine in Chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

Firefox is ignoring my margin-bottom css property. Works fine in Chrome.

My Code is simply:

```
 <input type="button" value="Continue Shopping" onClick="history.back(-1);" class="btn btn-orange pull-right mr10" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
```

What's happening is that the 'Continue Shopping' button is clipping over the product table.
http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/cart.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a previous answer mentioned, you are specifying `pull-right` on your `button` which floats the element to the right and breaks it out of the DOM. You can specify the inline style `clear:both;` that was mentioned, or you can go another route.

Since you are already using Bootstrap, you could wrap your `.btn` elements with a `div.row` element which would already include the `clear:both;` rule.

The bootstrap CSS has the following specified:

```
.row:after { clear:both; }
```

So, something like:

```
<div class="row">
     <a href="http://rsatestamls.kaliocommerce.com/checkout.aspx"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-orange pull-right" value="CheckOut"></a>
     <input type="button" style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="btn btn-orange pull-right mr10" onclick="history.back(-1);" value="Continue Shopping">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked flawlessly, and I learned a bit too! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, is there a reason you wrapped a submit button with an anchor element?